# Xamarin - ListView Displaying Data on IOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, viewmodel

My list views data displays correctly on UWP and Android but not for IOS. I think it has something to do with the `OnAppearing` method I'm using and when it actually gets called on IOS.

From my Dashboard when I navigate to an Item list page I have the following code behind on the `ItemPage`

```
public ItemPage(string category = null, bool fromDashboard = false)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = new ItemViewModel(category, fromDashboard);
}

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    var vm = BindingContext as ItemViewModel;
    vm?.GetData();
    base.OnAppearing();
}
```

Then in my `ItemViewModel` class I have a constructor that accepts a `category` and `fromDashboard` flag and sets some properties.

The `ItemViewModel` `GetData()` call is as follows:

```
public void GetData()
{
    this.Items = this.RefreshData(this.ItemService.GetAll(this.SelectedCategory));

    if (this.FromDashboard)
        this.Items = this.Items.Where(x => x.Status != "Complete").ToObservableCollection();
}
```

And then finally the `ItemPage.xaml` has a `ListView` with the `ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"`

For some reason this works fine on Windows and Android but no data will show on IOS. Is the page being rendered before the OnAppearing method or something?

Comment: Have you tried calling `RaisePropertyChanged` method in the `GetData` method after you set the items?

Comment: All my ViewModels inherit from a BaseViewModel which has the OnPropertyChanged method from INotifyPropertyChanged. Do I need to actually call manually?

Comment: Yes, you need to manually call it somewhere.

Comment: Adding it now at the end of the GetData method. Ill let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When editing values of ViewModel properties in the code, you have to call `OnPropertyChanged` method (from `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface) to let the UI know it has to update.

Like so:

```
public void GetData()
{
    this.Items = this.RefreshData(this.ItemService.GetAll(this.SelectedCategory));

    if (this.FromDashboard)
        this.Items = this.Items.Where(x => x.Status != "Complete").ToObservableCollection();

    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.Items));
}
```